# WebRTC video stream aspectRatio constraints does not work

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I am trying to use WebRTC video stream to capture selfi. Main intension to use on mobile web browsers. I tried defining aspectRatio : 9/16 which mostly works for mobile screen size.

On desktop using mobile simulator it works fine with 9/16 ratio but when test on actual Android or iOS device web browser it does not work and device show full wide screen video. Seems device does not respect the given aspectRatio.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const videoConstraint = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        facingMode: 'user',
        aspectRatio: { exact: 9 / 16 },
        frameRate: { min: 10, ideal: 30, max: 60 },
        resizeMode: 'none', 
    },
};

const CaptureSelfie = () => {
    const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>();
    const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>();
    
    const startVideoStream = async () => {
        await navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia(videoConstraint)
            .then((stream) => {
                videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
                videoRef.current.style.transform = 'scaleX(-1)';
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
      startVideoStream();
    }, []);


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div id="video">
            <video className="csc-videoPlayer" ref={videoRef} autoPlay></video>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
          </div>  
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default CaptureSelfie;
```

Comment: Some browsers / devices ignore unknown constraints without throwing an error. Can you try to detect if aspectRadio is present in the json returned by `navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think that you can use facingMode with WebRTC, [based on this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/facingMode).
Instead, try setting the camera:

`SelfieCaptureConfig.FRONT_CAMERA selfieCaptureConfigBuilder.setCameraType(SelfieCaptureConfig.FRONT_CAMERA)`

If that doesn't work and you don't get another response, you can ask on [peerConnection](https://community.daily.co/), a developer forum for WebRTC :)

Comment: Thanks. I have tested facingMode: 'user' or 'enviornment' it works fine on WebRTC for mobile web browser. It switches from front camera to back camera.